# My fitted model is too large to be uploaded to github despite the dataset not being very large

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am creating a **model** using **Linear Regression**, and after I create a file out of the model to be used, the size of it is greater than **400mb**. Github only allows 100mb files, so I am unable to commit and push which is required for using Heroku.

I am confused because the **shape of my training set is (3759, 10)** so 10 features, and 3759 observations.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import category_encoders as ce

#Create pipelines for different regressors
linear_regression = make_pipeline(
  ce.OneHotEncoder(use_cat_names = True),
  SimpleImputer(),  
  LinearRegression()
)


#Fit Models!
linear_regression.fit(X_train,y_train)


#Create file out of model
from joblib import dump
dump(linear_regression, 'linear_regression.joblib')
```

After I create a  file out of the model, I transfer it to a different folder to be used for an application. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated

Comment: What about compressing the data?

Comment: I am just not very experienced. How would I compress the data? I see that git has something called "Git LFS". Could this help?

Comment: If your data file is named `file.dat`, run this command on Linux:  `gzip -9 file.dat`  The compressed file will be named `file.dat.gz`  Add `-k` if you don't want the original file to be deleted.  `gzip -9 -k file.dat`

Comment: @ScottM, you are trying to dump only the model, not training data, right? after categorical encoding, what is the total no of features?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want to use git for this? Git is generally meant for storing and sharing source code, not outputs of your program. If you want to store this somewhere for another application to use you can always have this program write the dump to a database and have the application load from that database.

Comment: I would recommend Amazon RDS but if this is really the only item you need stored a relational database might be overkill. [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) may suit your needs better. The [code samples](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) seem pretty straightforward.